In React native, how to swap a two select component values onPress?
Trying to swap the values of the two components on Icon Press.
I have two components with Source Language and Destination Language, when the user press the Switch Icon then the values of the two components will be swapped
On Pressing the On press button, I would expect to switch the values of the two dropdown values

import { faArrowRightArrowLeft, faArrowsLeftRight } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg- 
icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { IconButton } from "react-native-paper";
import SelectDropdown from "react-native-select-dropdown";

const DropDown = () =>{
const[sourceLanguage, setSourceLanguage] = useState("");
const[destinationLanguage, setDestinationLanguage] = useState("");


const language = {
    source: null,
    destination: null
}

const languages = [
 {title: 'Amharic', value: 'Amharic'},
 {title: 'Arabic',  value: 'Arabic'}
]
useEffect(() =>{
    language.source = sourceLanguage
    

},[sourceLanguage])
useEffect(() =>{
    language.destination = destinationLanguage;
    

},[destinationLanguage])

const SwitchLanguages = () =>{
   console.log(language.destination.title)
   setSourceLanguage({ 
    ...language.destination,
    title:  language.destination.title,
    value: language.destination.value
    
    });
    
}
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

        <SelectDropdown
        data={languages}
        onSelect={(selectedItem, index) =>

            {
                setSourceLanguage(selectedItem)

            }}

        renderButton={(selectedItem, isOpened) =>
            {
            return(
                <View style={styles.dropdownButtonStyle}>
                    <Text style={styles.dropdownButtonTxtStyle}>
                        {selectedItem?.title || 'Select Source'}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            );

        }}
        renderItem={(item, index, isSelected) =>{
            return (
                <View style ={{
                    ...styles.dropdownItemStyle,
                    ...(isSelected && {backgroundColor : '#D2D9DF'})
                }}>
                    <Text style ={ styles.dropdownItemTxtStyle}>{item.title}</Text>
                </View>
            );

        }}
        dropdownStyle={styles.dropdownMenuStyle}
        />
        <View style={{width: 6}} />

           <TouchableOpacity 
           onPress={SwitchLanguages}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon 
            icon={faArrowRightArrowLeft}
            color="#FFF"
            size={20} />
           </TouchableOpacity>

            
        <View style={{width: 6}} />

        <SelectDropdown 
        data={languages}
        onSelect={(selectedItem, index) =>
        {
            setDestinationLanguage(selectedItem);
        
        }}
        renderButton={(selectedItem, isOpened) =>
        {
            return (
                <View style={styles.dropdownButtonStyle}>
                    <Text style={styles.dropdownButtonTxtStyle}> {selectedItem?.title || 'select Destination'} </Text>
                </View>

            );

        }}
        renderItem={(item, index, isSelected) =>
        {
            return (
                <View  style={{
                    ...styles.dropdownItemStyle,
                    ... (isSelected &&  {backgroundColor: '#D2D9DF'})
                }}>
                    <Text style={styles.dropdownItemTxtStyle}> {item.title}</Text>

                </View>
            );
        }}
        dropdownStyle={styles.dropdownMenuStyle}

        />

        
       
       
    </View>

);

}
export default DropDown;

The implementation likely doesn't work as expected because language is redeclared each render cycle back to the null values and isn't updated until the end of a render cycle when the useEffect hooks run and mutate that reference.
I think it's likely the case that language is unnecessary. You can enqueue the state updates to swap the sourceLanguage and destinationLanguage state values directly.
Consider the following example:
const languages = [
  { title: 'Amharic', value: 'Amharic' },
  { title: 'Arabic',  value: 'Arabic' },
];

const DropDown = () => {
  const[sourceLanguage, setSourceLanguage] = useState("");
  const[destinationLanguage, setDestinationLanguage] = useState("");

  const switchLanguages = () => {
    setSourceLanguage({ ...destinationLanguage });
    setDestinationLanguage({ ...sourceLanguage });
  }

  ...
};


Thanks Drew. I also had to set the value of the defaultValue of the dropdown in order to change the dropdown value. Much Love brother

@kiflay Did this answer sufficiently address your question?
